# scrollLeft on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've seen a few discussions about this around, but no solutions really. When I'm using Jquery 1.5 the "scrollLeft" property nor "scrollTop" work in Chrome. Not even on the jquery API page (http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

I'm using code like this:
$('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: a_position }, a_duration);

and have simplified it down to the most minimal code possible. Why won't this work? Once I saw it not working on the jquery website I began to think maybe it's just not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/animate-scrollleft-200-does-not-work-but-scrollleft-200-does

Comment: today (mid 2015) this is working:  $('html, body').animate( { scrollLeft : 320}) ( FF or Chrome using jQuery: 1.11.3)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to animate the scroll per se, workarounds are to animate position changes of top, left values.

If you're no relying on the animation part, you can use a

```
document.getElementById("pos-top").scrollIntoView();
```

as a workaround.